# Python: validation k-means clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to compare two different clusters computed with k-means library of `sklearn`.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

ya = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(Xa)
yb = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(Xb)
```

Where

```
ya
array([0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2,
       2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32)
```

and

```
yb
array([1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2,
       2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32)
```

The clusters are the same but the labels are different. In order to compute the difference I was doing:

```
sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,list(ya),list(yb))
sm.ratio()
```

But of course it does not work because of the labels. Is there any way to compare two clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual measure for comparing clusterings (or clusters and classes!) is thr **adjusted rand index** (ARI).

It solves *exactly* the problem that cluster numbers change.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, evaluation of clusterings with known targets is done using a [confusion matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix). You could use this in your case, even though neither is really a target.

If you just want to compare the arrays directly you can map the values of one to the other:

```
ya = np.array([{0:1, 2:2, 1:0}[a] for a in ya])
```

Comment: My problem is the label that is different even if the two clusters are the same

Comment: I updated the answer to map from one array to the other - does that work?

Comment: The problem is that the labeling seems to be random and you don't how it changes

Comment: I think that is down to the initialisation of the algorithm. If you set the random state seed to an integer, you should get the same result every time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way, probably  not very elegant, but it works

```
ya = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(Xa)
yb = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(Xb)

ya= KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(Xa)
cla = list()
m = 0
for i in range(0,3):
    tmp = np.where(ya == i)
    cla.append(list(tmp[0]))
cla = sort(cla)


yb= KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(Xb)
clb = list()
m = 0
for i in range(0,3):
    tmp = np.where(yb == i)
    clb.append(list(tmp[0]))
clb = sort(clb)
e = 0
for i in range(0,3):
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,list(cla[i]),list(clb[i]))
    e += 1 - sm.ratio()
```